# Kendo NumbericTextBox adding digits to value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We load up the cultures for kendo to use dynamically via a window variable. We have a ajax control which fetches and sets this for us then a function calls out to setup the numeric text boxes we have.

Here is a sample of the code that we are using to set it:

```
    $("#loeCompensationMin").kendoNumericTextBox({            
        format: "c",
        culture: window.CompensationCulture,
        value: window.CompensationMin,
        decimals: 2
    });
```

the culture is set up as "pt-BR" and the actual value is 605340.00 however after this the data is getting formatted as  "R$ 60.534.000,00". As you can see it is not formatting the data correctly, if I go in and remove the ".00" from the data prior to setting it here it loads up properly. but I shouldn't have to do this to the data before loading it up in the textbox should I?

--edit

going over the code in depth it seems that there was a the initial spot where it was being initialized in here it was getting set a value but not a culture. later on in the process we look up the culture based on the user and set the field. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe it's because your format is "c" which is currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that we were not setting an initial value for the culture. I change it that it would essentially default to en-us and then when the culture was changed it would change the value as expected.

So my guess is that kendo didn't know how to handle the change since it had no context for culture and formatted it as best it could for the new context but this would cause issues because of how the commas and periods are essentially flip flopped between the cultures.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$("#loeCompensationMin").kendoNumericTextBox({            
    format: "#.00",
    culture: window.CompensationCulture,
    value: window.CompensationMin,
    step: 0.01//set your increments here 
});
```

You had format set to `c` which is currency, `#.00` is a number with 2 decimal places.  And `step` is how much each click up or down will increment the value by.

Comment: @John then you might want to check and see if its something else.. because I tested it with the value you said you wanted and got it to work.  Plus I could never replicate what you did.